# Is there a way to ask an indefinite JsonPath whether it implies a given definite JsonPath?

Tags: java, jsonpath

I'm curious if, given a `JsonPath` that is known to be indefinite, there is a simple recipe where I can ask it if it would match another `JsonPath` known to be definite.  For example, a `JsonPath` representing `$..*` would imply any definite `JsonPath`.  I didn't see an obvious method [in the javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/latest/com/jayway/jsonpath/JsonPath.html).

Answer (score 0):

Jayway JSONpath has an option to output all the possible paths for a given jsonpath expression. Refer this [Path vs Value](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-vs-value). The output will be in *bracket notation*.

```
Configuration conf = Configuration.builder()
   .options(Option.AS_PATH_LIST).build();

List<String> pathList = using(conf).parse(json).read("$..*");
```

Online Test Tool : [Jayway JsonPath Evaluator](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/)

[image]

Comment: This only works given a document, correct?  That is, in the absence of a document there are no known paths to output.  I'm looking for the case where I have no document, a definite path in my left hand, and an indefinite path in my right hand.  Does the indefinite path in my right hand "match" the definite path in my left hand?

Comment: By document you mean JSON? If yes, the question itself is not making any sense to me. The output of  indefinite path is completely dependent on the document. Without it, it has no meaning. It can have 10 possible output path or 0 based on the document. IMO it would be completely wrong to compare without a document.

Comment: If you can create json(document) from the definite path. and then apply the above solution. You should be able to compare. But in any case you need the document.

Comment: I guess I was presuming wrongly that since surely JsonPath needs to perform this test internally it would have exposed the ability to "match" a definite path against an indefinite one without the need for a document.

Comment: A path is indefinite if it contains:

`..` - a deep scan operator,
`?(<expression>)` - an expression,
`[<number>, <number> (, <number>)]` - multiple array indexes https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#what-is-returned-when. I do not think there could be any test internally to satisfy all these conditions

Comment: For example `$.store.book[?(@.price < 10)]` is an indefinite path. Without document it has no meaning and hence your requirement is not applicable. You are probably confusing Wildcard(`*`) for indefinite path. If a query contains only wildcard the path is still definite.

Comment: `$..*` is indefinite because it contains a deep scan(`..`) operator. whereas just `$.*`  is definite and your requirement gets valid